# Lentitud en transición de imágenes de carrusel en Flutter

Tags: flutter

Estoy trabajando en un componente en Flutter que debe importar imágenes de la galería dentro de un formulario, de momento estoy pasándolas a base64 y eso se supone que es lo que dispondría al momento de mostrarlas.

Pero al investigar un poco como hacerlo y replicarlo veo que el rendimiento de transición entre cada unas de las imágenes es bastante lento.

El código simplificado es el siguiente:

Archivo **main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:proyecto/screens/test.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      initialRoute: 'master',
      home: TestScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Archivo **test.dart**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_swiper/flutter_swiper.dart';

class TestScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  List<String> imagenes = [
    "/9j/.../AKDP/9k=",
    "/9j//+ECj...//2Q=="
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 1.0),
        child: Swiper(
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){
            Uint8List bytes = base64Decode(imagenes[index]);
            MemoryImage image = MemoryImage( bytes );

            return Hero(
              tag: "imagen_$index",
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () { },
                  child: FadeInImage(
                    image: image,
                    placeholder: AssetImage('assets/img/no-image.jpg'),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          itemCount: imagenes.length,
          // pagination: new SwiperPagination(),
          // control: new SwiperControl(),
          itemWidth: _screenSize.width * 0.7,
          itemHeight: _screenSize.height * 0.3,
          layout: SwiperLayout.STACK,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Donde el arreglo de imágenes lo recorte para poder plasmarlo acá... pero bien pueden usar convertir por medio de esta [página](https://www.base64-image.de/) y usar las imágenes que ustedes deseen para recrear el problema, en caso que quieran ver a lo que hago referencia.

Sin embargo, agrego un gif con el comportamiento al que hago referencia.

[image: Transición lenta de imagenes]

Me gustaría que me den una idea quienes hayan trabajado imágenes en Flutter a ver que alternativas podría usar o que estoy haciendo mal.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: has probado con imagenes más pequeñas o usando  networkimage en lugar de MemoryImage solo para descartar ?

Comment: Con networkImage o assets funciona de maravilla, pero como tengo que adjuntar imágenes ya sea desde galería o desde cámara por eso había pensado en manejarlo por base64.

Comment: ok entiendo, el problema es que el `base64Decode` está tomando mucho tiempo, es por eso el delay, lo mejor sería que uses FutureBuilder o alguna función asíncrona para que hagas el decode de todas las imagenes primero y luego las usas en el carousel

Comment: Si necesitas ayuda en eso puedes preguntar :)

Comment: Justamente estaba tratando de hacer la prueba según lo que me indicabas para ver si en realidad solucionaba el problema antes de dar una respuesta... y así fue. Voy a colocar una respuesta con la solución.

Comment: genial ,evita hacer tareas pesadas dentro del método build :) y cuando ya sean muy muy pesadas puedes usar Isolates

Comment: Nunca había escuchado ese Widget... voy a investigar un poco. Gracias por el apoyo :)

Comment: Dale, no es un widget, es un concepto, revisa este video donde lo explican claramente (solo que en inglés) : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vl_AaCgudcY   , tambien puedes seguir un canal de youtube que tengo con un amigo donde hablamos flutter en español : https://www.youtube.com/c/TheDartSide

Answer (score 0):

Haciendo uso de un FutureBuilder se mejora el rendimiento de las transiciones. Por tanto cambie el builder de la siguiente forma.

Archivo **test.dart**

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 1.0),
        child: FutureBuilder<List<MemoryImage>>(
          future: Future.value(
            imagenes.map((item) => MemoryImage( base64Decode(item) )).toList()
          ),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<MemoryImage>> snapshot) {

            if( snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.length > 0 ) {
              return Swiper(
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                  return Hero(
                    tag: "imagen_$index",
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () { },
                        child: FadeInImage(
                          image: snapshot.data[index],
                          placeholder: AssetImage('assets/img/no-image.jpg'),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                itemCount: imagenes.length,
                // pagination: new SwiperPagination(),
                // control: new SwiperControl(),
                itemWidth: _screenSize.width * 0.7,
                itemHeight: _screenSize.height * 0.3,
                layout: SwiperLayout.STACK,
              );
            } 

            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```